# Collisions are getting ignored by child objects in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I am working on a game in unity where my character controller on a child object is not colliding with any other objects. I have tried using colliders with and without rigidbody, but still the character is not colliding with colliders.

It only collides if the collider or character controller is attached to the parent object containing the root motion animator. Why is this happening? I want my collider to jump with character. I tried to attach the collider with bones but that doesn't collide either.

[Collision bug video](https://youtu.be/hK7Vt_FMgtI)

Comment: How is the player moving? Are you using the character controller?

Comment: I am using root motion animation to move character. I ma using character controller for collisions and physics. Moreover when i use the character controller with parent player object, the collisions are working fine, but it doesn't work when I use character controller on any child object.

Comment: I'm guessing because it's a child of the parent and you're moving the parent the child character controller will just teleport along or something like that. I don't know much about root motion animation, but that'd be my guess. Sorry I couldn't help more

Comment: thank you though. I was trying to make the character controller getting jumped with animation too, so I was doing that. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: Do you have gravity working?

Comment: yes, gravity is working